# Mock SearchResultCollection

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I need mock `SearchResultCollection` something like:

```
Mock<SearchResultCollection> mock = new Mock<SearchResultCollection>();
mock.Setup(collection => collection.SOME_PROPERTY).Returns(SOME_RETURN_VALUE);
```

How implement mocking?